# PHP timer to send email once when timer runs out

Tags: php, email, timer

guys i know this has probably got an answer but I just can't seem to glean what I need to get this done.

I have a PHP script on my server that should send an email once a timer runs down.

The information echoed in the timer can't change as its got a few scripts that read from it.

Problem is i can't seem to limit the email to just one....it sends hundreds.

I've tried adding a variable that the if function switches off to prevent the email triggering again but it just won't work.

Really in need of some help.

```
<?php
$curr = time();
$date = strtotime("Dec 08, 2014 7:43PM");
$diff = $date - $curr;
$diff_dd = floor($diff / 86400);
$diff %= 86400;
$diff_hh = floor($diff / 3600);
$diff %= 3600;
$diff_mm = floor($diff / 60);
$diff %= 60;
$diff_ss = $diff;
$all = diff_dd + $diff_hh + $diff_mm + $diff_ss;
echo sprintf("%02d%02d%02d%02d",$diff_dd,$diff_hh,$diff_mm, $diff_ss);

if($diff == 0)

{
$Email --;
$to = "x@X.com";
$subject = "text";
$txt = "text";
$headers = "From: notification@X.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set `diff` to the time difference between some date and now, then modify that value when figuring out the days, hours, minutes, etc., then test if `diff` is zero. When you do the test `diff` is the number of seconds, not the original diff. The e-mail looks like it would be sent every minute.

Comment: I think this is what is happening i'm assuming the seconds value is going to run to zero or exactly "0" to trigger the email. is it the case that we have say 410 seconds left and it is sending each time the last digit hits zero? as im getting an email every 10 seconds not every minute as it is above?

Comment: If the intention is to send the e-mail once when the timer runs out, why not just compare the results of `$date - $curr`, without doing all the other calculations. When the value is less than some threshold, like Zero, then the message is sent. But since the value will now always be less than zero you need to disable the ability to send the message again (i.e., clear the test, clear the reference date, set a **been there, done that** flag, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the $diff after it sends, so in the if condition just add `$diff= -1;` or just reset the time, or in the if condition just change the expression. or even set it to trigger on 1 rather than 0.

you just need to stop the cycle... i think if the number is negative it will still return a 0 (happened few times but not sure where) so make sure you stop it and not rely on it going to negative.

Comment: i totally agree i tried adding an enabled variable:

Comment: As in:

$Enabled = true:

Comment: and then in the if statement 

    if($Enabled && $diff = 0)
    Email stuff
    Enabled == false;

The value never changes to stop the email..?

The intention is to manually reset the time later as its to run for a certain time and then Im prompted to reset it via the email.

Comment: make sure that $Enabled is being set only once... if every time the script runs it resets it to true then it is not going to stop.. also try setting it to send at 1 rather than 0